# assign value to the object without specifying key in Javascript

Tags: javascript, reactjs

In this React Todo List app tutorial https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Rh3tobg7hEo on minute 26:30, there is a function called toggleTodo which takes id and the e.target.checked as an argument and it updates the state of "todos" (one React useStage object) by map and returning { ...todo, completed} object.

```
const [todos, setTodos] = useState()

function toggleTodo(id, completed) {
 setTodos(currentTodos => {
  return currentTodos.map(todo => {
    if (todo.id === id) {
      return { ...todo, completed }
    }
    return todo
  })
})}

  return (
<>
  <h1 className="header">Todo List</h1>
  <TodoList todos={todos} toggleTodo={toggleTodo} deleteTodo={deleteTodo} />
</>
```

)

and on the TodoList.jsx:

```
export function TodoItem({ completed, id, title, toggleTodo, deleteTodo }) {

return (
<li>
  <label>
    <input
      type="checkbox"
      checked={completed}
      onChange={e => toggleTodo(id, e.target.checked)}
    />
    {title}
  </label>
  <button onClick={() => deleteTodo(id)} className="btn btn-danger">
    Delete
  </button>
</li> )}
```

the full code can be found here: https://github.com/WebDevSimplified/react-todo-list

my question is why the update function is not returning { ...todo, completed: completed} ? isn't the e.target.checked return only true or false, then when we set the object property we need to specify the key, not just passing true or false, this should be invalid { ...todo, completed} isn't it? how come the completed variable which is a boolean value being added into the object without specifying a key? Am I missing something?

Comment: `{ ...todo, completed }` === `{ ...todo, completed: completed }`